# Standard Entreprise program / Individual program

Tags: iphone, ios

i am developing an iOS application for a client (Company ), i use my account witch is a Standard Individual program, and my client have purchased a Standard Company Program.

Now i would like to publish in the App Store  the application under the name of the company of my client.

how to do this please?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the client already has a standard license, you may ask them for the app store profile and certificate. Create the distributable using that certificate and ask the client to submit the app(which is assuming that the client would bot give you their agent credentials for the iTunes Connect).